# Роутинг в React приложении

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Возникла проблема с роутингом в React приложении. У меня есть две страницы: Customer ('/') и Admin ('/admin'). На странице Customer стоит переключатель между компонентами. Так вот, на локальной машине всё хорошо, но как только загружаю на Netlify появляются проблемы. При перезагрузке страницы появляется ошибка "Page not found".

Обычно смена BrowserRouter на HashRouter решает эту проблему, но у меня вложенный роутер и с ним не работает.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Admin from "./pages/Admin/Admin";
import Customer from "./pages/Customer/Customer";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename="/">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Customer} />
        <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Customer.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Container from "../../components/Container/Container";
import Navbar from "../../components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Home from "../../pages/Home/Home";
import Footer from "../../components/Footer/Footer";
import "./customer.scss";
import Rules from "../Rules/Rules";

const Customer = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="customer">
        <Container>
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/rules" component={Rules} />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </Container>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default Customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил добавив файл _redirects в папку public.

**_redirects**

```
/* /index.html 200
```